# adding a dom id on a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component as

```
<Component />
```

---

```
render(){
   return <div>Component </div>
}
```

and I would like to render it in the dom with an additional id, passing it like

```
<Component id={'myId'} />
```

I do not want to change the internal render of `<Component />` and I would like to do not wrap it.

Is it possible to achieve this in react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not want to change the internal render of  and I would like to do not wrap it.

If by "change the internal render of `<Component />`" you mean changing what you're returning from its `render`, then you're out of luck. Doing that or wrapping it are your only options; once rendered, the `div` **is** your component's top-level element. There's nowhere else to put the `id`.

So you'd put it on the `div`:

```
render() {
    return <div id={this.props.id}>Component </div>;
}
```

Live Example *(using `Example` rather than `Component` to avoid confusion)*:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div id={this.props.id}>Component </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example id={'myId'} />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

If you right-click the text "Component" above and examine the DOM, you'll find that the component isn't wrapped or anything like that. (The `id="root"` element you see is just where I mounted it in the DOM, since React warns against mounting directly on `document.body`.)

Comment: I rather prefer to do not change the div inside the comp

Comment: @Radex: That or wrapping it are your only options. Once rendered, your component's top-level element **is** the `div`. There's nowhere else to put the `id`.